# how to use \twocolumn in amsart document class in latex?

Tags: two-column

I am typing in the following way in my manuscript.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\title{differential equations}
\author{sastry}
\begin{abstract} 
some text 
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\twocolumn
\section{introduction}
----some data------
\end{document}
```

When I follow the above manner. I got the two column from introduction onward. But after abstract it moves to next column and then it starts double column.

So my question is:
How to get introduction immediate of abstract in two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the multicol package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\title{differential equations}
\author{sastry}

\begin{abstract} 
  some text 
\end{abstract}

  \maketitle

  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \section{introduction}
  ----some data------

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not post Thanks you comment ! Please you the mark system.

Comment: If amsart is being used as specified by a journal publication you would need to check if they support use of multicol to change the journal layout.

Answer (score 2):

As for the standard classes, it is better to use the `twocolumn` option which sets up the whole design for two column, as opposed to using a one column setup but then locally switching to `\twocolumn`, the latter is really intended for special sections like indices set two column in a one column document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\title{differential equations}
\author{sastry}
\begin{abstract} 
some text 
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{introduction}
\def\z{ --- some data --- }
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z
\end{document}
```